# Matrix algebra involving exponents

Tags: matrices

[image]

I tried it with choice A and it worked but why is C correct?

I see if you multiple both sides of the equation in choice C by the inverse (A^-1), then I'll get the condition from the question. Why isn't choice A correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A^3=I$, then $A^4$=$A^3A=IA=A$.

The answer choice (a) is incorrect because we can't necessarily say this; consider this matrix, for example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^3=I$$

Answer (score 3):

If $A^3=I$ then $A=I$ might be true, but it might not.  The question asks which of the following **must** be true (even with **must** in bold type), so an equation which **might** be true does not answer the question.